# Trying to get Pageviews/Bounce Rates, etc. based on Custom Dimensions

Tags: google-analytics, custom-dimensions

I have a bunch of custom dimensions. Publications 1, 2, and 3 are dimensions 6-8. For any given article on our site, we may or may not push all 3. For this report I am interested in capturing traffic from a recent airshow. The possible publication combinations are:

```
Pub1: 2015
Pub2: EBACE Convention News
```

or

```
Pub1: EBACE Convention News
Pub2: 2015
```

or (notice the shift to 2-3 now, if an editor assigns Pub1 to something else)

```
Pub2: EBACE Convention News
Pub3: 2015
```

What I now would like to do is a "how the airshow" went type of report, where I can say we had X number of page views for any of these combinations, here was the bounce rate, etc.

I tried using Custom Segments (see criteria below) but they apparently won't work because they're session-based and once a user goes to any of these pages, subsequent page visits from the same session count towards my numbers, and might not be one of these pages.

[image: Custom Segment Criteria]

Is there a way to do this? **Along these same lines, should I be passing all 3 Pub values into one custom dimension as an array instead of splitting it like this?**

Comment: I think you should explain the purpose of these custom dimension "Publication". Also, if they are related to the single article, why didn't you simply put the scope to hit level?

Comment: The scope IS set to hit level. It's a magazine. We can simplify this and just say that "June 2015" is a Publication we pass to GA. So after the month ends, my editors ask me, "How many Page Views did we get for June 2015 stories?" or "What was our bounce rate for June 2015 stories."

Comment: Oh sorry, that was custom segments. Anyway: you have to be consistent. When you talk about custom dimensions, you can't talk about "combination". Custom dimension in Slot 1 should be always for one thing only.
Now, just go to Behavior -> Site Content -> All Pages and add as secondary dimension a custom dimension, then filter it. 
But in that way you can check one dimension at a time, then do your math. So, It would be better to create a custom report, or even better to import data to Google sheets.

Comment: Let me know so I can give you a complete answer.